# How to properly return a selected value(string) from a dropdown menu?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently attempting to get the value from a dropdown menu and use it where the dropdown widget is called. The dropdown menu uses a list of strings for it's data, so I just need to return the string that the user selects. I'm going to pass that selected string into another dropdown widget for it to use. I'm having issues figuring out how to return the selected string from it's dropdown widget. Any help is appreciated!

This is where I call the dropdown widgets. The first one is the one where I need to get the selected value. I'm going to pass that selected value into the second one.

```
              Container(
                  child: RecurringTypeDropDown()),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                  child: RecurringCategoryDropdown()),
```

This is the dropdown widget where I need to return it's selected value so the value can be passed into the other dropdown widget.

```
class RecurringTypeDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecurringTypeDropDownState createState() => _RecurringTypeDropDownState();
}

class _RecurringTypeDropDownState extends State<RecurringTypeDropDown> {
  var currentSelectedValue;
  final dropTypes = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              child: FormField<String>(
                builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    child: InputDecorator(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: Text("Choose an Option", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                          value: currentSelectedValue,
                          isDense: true,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              return currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                            });
                            print(currentSelectedValue);
                          },
                          items: dropTypes.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `GlobalKey` and assign to `RecurringTypeDropDown(key: _key1)` 
To get value, do `(_key1.currentState as _RecurringTypeDropDownState).currentSelectedValue;` 
code snippet

```
class RecurringTypeDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  RecurringTypeDropDown({Key key}) : super(key: key);

... 
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key1 = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _key2 = GlobalKey();
  String value1 = "";
  String value2 = "";
  
  void _incrementCounter() {
    value1 = (_key1.currentState as _RecurringTypeDropDownState)
        .currentSelectedValue;
    value2 = (_key2.currentState as _RecurringTypeDropDownState)
        .currentSelectedValue;

...
RecurringTypeDropDown(key: _key1),
SizedBox(height: 10),
RecurringTypeDropDown(key: _key2),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RecurringTypeDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  RecurringTypeDropDown({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RecurringTypeDropDownState createState() => _RecurringTypeDropDownState();
}

class _RecurringTypeDropDownState extends State<RecurringTypeDropDown> {
  var currentSelectedValue;
  final dropTypes = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
      child: FormField<String>(
        builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.white),
            child: InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: Text("Choose an Option",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                  value: currentSelectedValue,
                  isDense: true,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      return currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                    });
                    print(currentSelectedValue);
                  },
                  items: dropTypes.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    )));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key1 = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _key2 = GlobalKey();
  String value1 = "";
  String value2 = "";
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    value1 = (_key1.currentState as _RecurringTypeDropDownState)
        .currentSelectedValue;
    value2 = (_key2.currentState as _RecurringTypeDropDownState)
        .currentSelectedValue;

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RecurringTypeDropDown(key: _key1),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            RecurringTypeDropDown(key: _key2),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text("$value1"),
            Text("$value2"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created different widget classes for both of your drop down. I think if they are not reusable, then no need to create widget class. Just create functions. Then you can simply add selected value from RecurringTypeDropDown to the drop down list of RecurringCategoryDropdown(and then setState), as both of your functions are going to be in same class.